# Port Routing / Proxy for PC for incoming traffic?

Tags: windows, powershell, proxy, ip, port

I have a domain let's call it (testserver.com) that points to my PC IP (192.XXX.X.X), I need to setup a rule/proxy/something that will make all connections from testserver.com goes to 192.XXX.X.X:8080, sorry if this is a stupid or impossible question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, @Daniel might have a good suggestion there, it would ofc be easier to work with names.
So, I have just gone to the Windows Firewall with Advanced settings, here are the steps I think are to do for incoming traffic.

First: Add an Inbound-connection-rule:
[inbound connection rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxtK0.png)

Second: Choose the Option "Port"

[rule that controls a connection for an TCP or UDP port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlNsO.png)

Third: Choose your protocol type, TCP or UDP and select the second option below, write 8080

[define protocol and port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mlT9.png)

Fourth: Now choose if only secured connection(s) should be allowed or also not-secured

[choose option for network security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6PjP.png)

Fifth: Now select if domain, public connection or private connection

[network type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHXtQ.png)

Sixth: Now add name and description of the rule

[name and desc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/745uA.png)

Seventh: Go to properties of your (new) rule

Eighth: Now you can check the different tabs and also change the protocol from UDP or TCP to any other. The tab "Scope" will let you define IP-adress(es) for this connection that are either public or private, for this connection. In case you're interested, you can also define Authorized computers for this connection, but the connection must be secured then.

[the IP scope section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KluDg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set rules for incoming or outgoing traffic in the Windows Firewall. I cannot tell you the exact steps currently, as I am not home. Tho I found this post helpful:

https://serverfault.com/questions/496335/open-windows-firewall-to-all-connections-from-specific-ip-address

If you still need help, I would watch later. But actually the Windows Firewall should be quite easy to manage.

Comment: well for my it still looks a bit like black magic so please if you would be able to solve my problem when you get home i would be very greatfull, i will explain it more carefully now myb?
I have a domain let's call it (testserver.com) and it's set to mine PC ip 192.XXX.X.X , i need to redirect all incoming traffic from that domain to 192.XXX.X.X:8080 (here is mine testserver for presentation at local network) so everybody will be able to see mine demo just by typing testserver.com instead of 192.XXX.X.X:8080 (it looks coller and more proffesional)

Comment: @Ignacy, if it doesn't have to be testserver.com you should be able to access by your computer's hostname e.g. `PresentationPC1:8080`.  If you don't know your computer name you can find out by typing `$env:computername` at a powershell prompt